# Finding day of a date in Java

Tags: java, date, datetime

I want to find out the day of the date in Java for a date like `27-04-2011`.

I tried to use this, but it doesn't work:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
int val = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
```

It gives the integer value, not the String output I want.  I am not getting the correct value I want.  For example it is giving me value `4` for the date `28-02-2011` where it should be 2 because Sunday is the first week day.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you've asked it for the day of the week - and February 28th was a [Monday, day 2](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.util.Calendar.MONDAY). Note that in the code you've given, you're not actually *setting* the date anywhere - it's just using the current date, which is a Wednesday, which is why you're getting 4. If you could show how you're trying to set the calendar to a different date (e.g. 28th of February) we can work out why that's not working for you.

If you want it formatted as text, you can use [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) and the "E" specifier. For example (untested):

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE");
String text = formatter.format(cal.getTime());
```

Personally I would avoid using `Calendar` altogether though - use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net), which is a far superior date and time API.

Comment: if you give me an example of using SimpleDateFormat here, it would be really helpful for me.

Comment: @riyana: I've added a sample, but I really would *strongly* encourage you to use Joda Time instead.

Comment: @JonSkeet : +1 for answer, i was looking for same.

Answer (score 3):

```
Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("EEE").format(cal.getTime()));
```

---

**Output**

```
Wed
```

---

**See Also**

- [SimpleDateFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Answer (score 3):

```
  String dayNames[] = new DateFormatSymbols().getWeekdays();
  Calendar date1 = Calendar.getInstance();
  System.out.println("Today is a " 
    + dayNames[date1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)]);
```

Answer (score 2):

See the JavaDoc of the DAY_OF_WEEK field. It points to 7 constants SUNDAY..SATURDAY that show how to decode the int return value of cal.get(Calendary.DAY_OF_WEEK). Are you sure that

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(2011, 02, 28);
cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
```

returns the wrong value for you?

Comment: I can assure you, that this is working ;)
scala> import java.util.Calendar
scala> val cal=Calendar.getInstance()
scala> cal.set(2011, 02, 28)
scala> cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)
res1: Int = 2

Answer (score 2):

## *java.time*

The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

Also, quoted below is a notice at the [Home Page of Joda-Time](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/):

> Note that from Java SE 8 onwards, users are asked to migrate to java.time (JSR-310) - a core part of the JDK which replaces this project.

**Solution using `java.time`, the modern Date-Time API:**

```
import java.time.DayOfWeek;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.TextStyle;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "27-04-2011";
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d-M-u", Locale.ENGLISH);
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(input, dtf);
        DayOfWeek dow = date.getDayOfWeek();
        System.out.println(dow);

        // String value
        String strDay = dow.getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL, Locale.ENGLISH);
        System.out.println(strDay);
        strDay = dow.getDisplayName(TextStyle.SHORT, Locale.ENGLISH);
        System.out.println(strDay);

        // Alternatively
        strDay = date.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEEE", Locale.ENGLISH));
        System.out.println(strDay);
        strDay = date.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE", Locale.ENGLISH));
        System.out.println(strDay);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
WEDNESDAY
Wednesday
Wed
Wednesday
Wed
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/GXtNII)

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Try following:

```
    Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
    int val = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
    System.out.println(new DateFormatSymbols().getWeekdays()[val]);
```

or

```
    Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
    String dayName = new DateFormatSymbols().getWeekdays()[cal
            .get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)];
    System.out.println(dayName);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(2011, 2, 28);
     int val = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
     System.out.println(val);
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at [SimpleDateFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) and propably [Locale](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you need the exact date value in the month you need to use Calendar:DAY_OF_MONTH it will return the exact date in the month starting from 1.

```
//Current date is 07-06-2021 and this will return 7
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
int val = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
System.out.println("Date in month:"+val);

//If you want the day of the week in text better use the 
//SimpleDateFormat, since Calendar API will return the integer value in 
// the week if we given Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK
String dayWeekText = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE").format(cal.getTime());
System.out.println("Day of week:"+dayWeekText);
```

As suggested in the comment Java Date API have all these feature available. Java 8 introduced new APIs for Date and Time to address the shortcomings of the older java.util.Date and java.util.Calendar.

The same can be achieved using Date API in Java

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse("2021-06-08"); //2021 June 08 Tuesday
System.out.println(localDate.dayOfWeek().getAsText()); //Output as : Tuesday
System.out.println(localDate.dayOfWeek().getAsShortText()); //Output as : Tue
System.out.println(localDate.dayOfMonth().get()); //Output as current date
```

Comment: The classes `Calendar`and `SimpleDateFormat` that you use are poorly designed and for that reason were officially replaced by [java.time, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) in 2014. What is the point in suggesting their use now, 7 years later?